# Como puedo hacer el movimiento y que la camara siga al personaje?

Tags: c#, unity3d, 3d

estoy haciendo un juego en Unity 2019.4.29f1 y no se como va el movimiento además de que por alguna razón cuando me muevo el personaje (un cubo) desaparece así sin mas.
No se porque pasa esto ya que los objetos lo tengo todo puesto donde es. Además de que en las consolas de Unity y de VisualStudio en ninguna me da error alguno no se que pasa. por favor explicarlo fácil porque soy nuevo en la programación gracias.
no se que mas poner para que me deje publicar esta pregunta
madremia que mas puedo poner para dar mas detalles[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public Player Jugador;
    public Camera Cam;
    public float velocidad, sensibilidadH, sensibilidadV;
    private float rotateHorizontal;
    private float rotateVertical;
    public int vidaMax;
    public int vidaMin;
    public int _vida;
    public bool daño;
    public GameObject Target;
    public GameObject ejeTarget;
    public float t;
    private Vector3 posicionRelativa;
    


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() 
    {
        velocidad = 1;
        vidaMax = 100;
        vidaMin = 0;
        _vida = vidaMax;
        print("Vida es igual:" + _vida);
        print("¿Recibiendo daño?" + daño);
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(velocidad * Time.deltaTime, 0));

            transform.localScale = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(-velocidad * Time.deltaTime, 0));

            transform.localScale = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(velocidad * Time.deltaTime, 0));

            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(velocidad * Time.deltaTime, 0));

            transform.localScale = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
        }

        
        /*void Movement()
        {
            transform.position += transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical")
            * velocidad * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position += transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")
            * velocidad * Time.deltaTime;

            Vector3 cameraForward = Cam.transform.forward;
            cameraForward.y = 0f;
            transform.forward = Vector3.Slerp(transform.forward, cameraForward,
            0.05f);
        }*/
        void CameraMove()
        {
            Cam.transform.position =
            Vector3.Lerp(Cam.transform.position, Target.transform.position,
             Mathf.SmoothStep(0.0f, 1.0f, t));
            // rotateVertical ‐= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")* sensitivityV;
            rotateHorizontal += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") *
            sensibilidadH;
            ejeTarget.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f,
            rotateHorizontal, 0.0f);
            Cam.transform.LookAt(transform.position);
           
        }
        void restarVida()
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.M))
            {
                daño = true;
                _vida = _vida - 10;
                daño = false;
            }
            
        }


    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que un objeto siga a otro, lo que tendrías que hacer es hacer que **la cámara sea hija del jugador.** Para ello solo tienes que arrastrar en la jerarquía la cámara dentro del Player (como hiciste con el cubo).

Respecto a lo que comentabas sobre que el personaje se caía al moverse, no puedo encontrar ningún error en tu código. ¿Qué componentes tienes en el suelo (plane)?

Un saludo :)

Comment: hola gracias por la ayuda al final ya lo solucione solo pero de todas formas gracias